# Why do we say "of mine/of his" instead of "of me/of him"?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, personal-pronouns, double-possessive

> He's a friend of **mine**.
>   That's a car of **his**.

Why do we use the possessive when the meaning would be the same while not using it (e.g. *a friend of me* and *a car of him*)?  I thought maybe it is short for *That's a car of **his [cars]***, but I have no way of making sure; it sounds a little odd that way to me.

Comment: He's a friend of *mine*, but he's [not the boss of me](http://www.newstatesman.com/society/2009/05/cameras-asthma-monitored).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're examples of the [double genitive/possessive](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/FAQdoublegenitive.htm), which is perfectly valid and has been around in English for centuries. The *of* already denotes "possession", but we do this again when we use *mine/his* instead of *me/him*.

The fact that we don't say *John is a friend of me/him* is really just idiomatic for those particular forms. But that "idiomatic principle" isn't universally observed - people often say, for example, *He's a friend of John*. Though they also say *a friend of John's* - both forms are valid there.

[Here's an NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=friend%20of%20her,friend%20of%20hers&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) showing how *friend of her* has gradually given way to *friend of hers* over the past couple of centuries, as the "reach" of the idiomatic *mine/his* has been extended.

Comment: The tail end of that Ngram tells me she has fewer and fewer friends as time goes on.

Comment: @onomatomaniak: She might have got more for all I know. People might become *her friends* rather than *friends of her[s]*.

Comment: Good, except "of" does not always indicate possession. It may also be used to indicate an attribute associated with but not possessed by a person or thing. For example, "kind words of yours" (whose?) versus "kind of you". (of whom?). Consider here German dative versus genitive cases.

Comment: @Jack Robbin: That's what I meant by putting "possession" in quotes.

Comment: There is a slight difference on occasion. _He's a friend of John's connotes_ 'one of (the set of) John's friends' whereas _Fredonia is an enemy of Ruritania_ doesn't necessarily mean that there are other enemies.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: Which is as much as to say you don't buy into the concept of "double genitive/possessive". Your interpretation *(of John's = of John's [friends])* has been kicked around on [this earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50588/) but I can't say I recall a lot of support for it. One might as well say that if Fredonia is **an** enemy, (as opposed to **the** enemy), that in itself implies the existence of other enemies.

Comment: The Cambridge Idioms Dictionary contains: 'if a sword of Damocles hangs over someone, they are in a situation where something bad is likely to happen to them very soon'. Perhaps Mrs Damocles was once asked by a neighbour, before the Dionysius incident, "Is this a sword of Damocles's?"

Answer (score -3):

We all should know that

Prepositions are usually followed by a Noun (That's why it is called preposition - **Pre + Position.** The word whose position is just before a Noun.)

Now consider two sentences

> - This is my pen and that is your pen. (Right sentence)

but if we don't want repetition, so we avoid *"pen"*

The sentence gets short

This is my pen and that is yours.

NOTE: ***"yours"*** **includes a noun**, which is *a pen*

but

***"your"* DOESN'T include a noun**

similarly

"Hers" includes a noun

"HER" DOESN'T include a noun

now as told earlier, **propositions are placed before a noun**.

So, There is a friend of...? My/mine??

*"My" doesn't include a noun*

**"Mine" includes a noun.**

***After** a **preposition***, **there has to be a noun or a noun case** *(possessive pronoun)*

> - There is a friend **of mine** - is right
> - ... of me   - is wrong.

Comment: We normally say ....it is bad of he/him????

Comment: Because you are a new contributor we (EL&U veterans and fogies) are expected to be "gentle" and kind towards you. But, I'm afraid, this looks like a terrible answer. Why the need to punctuate so many words in capital letters? Writing in all caps is considered rude, people will think you are shouting and this coupled with the excessive use of ellipses (…) and question marks (?) makes the answer very hard to read and follow. It does not look professional in the slightest. Please fix the formatting.

Comment: user @bookmanu deserves a special badge for tidying up the answer. My downvote still remains though. The OP is asking about "mine" and "his" in place of "of me" and "of him".