# How should I correctly repeat possessives?

Tags: word-choice, differences, grammaticality, possessives

> 1. planning of mine, the student and the company
> 2. planning of mine, the student's, and the company's

Which is correct/better, and why?  I would assume 2 is correct, but is 1 incorrect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2 is correct and 1 is incorrect.  This is because without the possessive *-'s*, there is nothing to show that *student* and *company* are possessive.

However, even 2 isn't written very well.  It's standard to place yourself last in a list, and it looks a little clunky to have more possessive endings in a row than you can help:

> Planning by the student, the company, and me.

Note that *planning of mine* would be [completely fine](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/45371/10041) (double genitive, as you noted); it's simply that the idiomatic double genitive is not common when the possessor is not represented by a pronoun (e.g. *planning of the student's*), and even less common in lists (e.g. *planning of the student's, the parents', the school's...*).

Answer (score 4):

1 is certainly wrong, as @Daniel has explained.  But 2 is confusing enough to be dubious, though not quite wrong.  Far better to avoid repeated possessives entirely, as in "...planning by myself, the student and the company."

Comment: Or maybe: "... planning by the student, the company, and me." Or get rid of the preposition "... the student's, the company's, and my planning..."